# matplotlib yticks elements too far to each other, and problem on ticks spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I control the spacing between subplot's y ticks? I have 2 scatter plots on a subplot, on the first scatter plot the Ys are always equal to 0, and on the second scatter plot I have a y values that are ranging from 7.0 to 7.25 and more. There is too much space between 0 and 7, and there is no space between from 7 to 7.25( it should be like this 0, 7.000,7.005,7.010,7.015,7.020,7.025,~~)[image]

### Update sample code

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3
x = [x for x in range(100)]
y=[random.uniform(7, 8) for x in range(100)]
y1=[0 for x in range(100)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.scatter(x,y1)
fig.show()
```

Comment: for higher video resolution https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ant-SckYa-42g9kcOE6UVl5W1l6d3g?e=vf4ZbM

Comment: Some code would help to see what you are doing.  My guess is you are manually setting your ticks, and this is the result. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Are you sure you are potting your data as number and not strings?

Comment: @JodyKlymak if I did not set the ticks this will be the result. the space is still there https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ant-SckYa-42g9ke1VPCKHOXNvLeKw?e=spFumQ

Comment: What space are you referring to?

Comment: If you want to have more dynamic range around 0 and around 7, either subtract 7 from the blue curve, or plot then in two different subplots.